# Configuring a Trigger to Spawn a New EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

What would be the best way to automate the creation of an EC2 instance? For an example, if an object is created in a S3 bucket I want to spawn a new EC2 and then copy that object to the EC2. I can do the copying part using an init script but how can I spawn the EC2?

Can a SNS alert be configured to get triggered when an object is created and then  automatically spawn an EC2 instance? Or do I need to use something like Lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make S3/PutObject trigger a Lambda. The Lambda function will launch an instance. Since Lambdas are for short duration, you may not want to wait for the instance to be up and running. Launch the instance and pass the S3 bucket as part of user data.

If you choose Python to write your Lambda function, it comes with Boto3 library. Use Boto3 to launch a EC2 instance. Make sure your Lambda function has required privileges to launch an instance.